# Modifying multiple headers in word doc using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am currently using the Word reference in C# to open and modify a word document.  Some of the content that needs to be modified is in the headers, and am using the following code to account for that.

```
foreach(Range rng in doc.StoryRanges){
   rng.Find.Execute(ref findVar, ref isTrue, ref isTrue, ref isFalse, 
   ref isFalse, ref isFalse, ref isTrue, ref isOne, 
   ref isFalse, ref replaceVar, ref isTwo, ref isFalse, 
   ref isFalse, ref isFalse, ref isFalse);
}
```

The issue is that my document has two unique headers.  The first is comprised of the first 4 pages, and then on the 5th page it is a different header.  It is marked in Word as "Header -Section 2-".  I have not been able to find a code snippit that will allow me to make any modifications in this second header.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a code snippit at this site that is able to do a find and replace throughout the entire document: http://www.wwco.com/~wls/blog/2010/07/03/find-and-replace-in-word-using-c-net/

This will iterate through all parts of the document, so no parts are missed.